# Escaping ? mark in regex for Codeigniter routes

Tags: regex, codeigniter, routes

I have a URI route specified in my routes.php file like this:

```
$route['(.+)/schoolid\?'] = 'somepage';
```

However, when I enter `random/schoolid?`, it displays a 404 page instead of displaying 'somepage' as specified in the URI route. 'somepage' does exist, coz if I simply take out `\?`, it displays somepage upon visiting `random/schoolid`

I also attempted to use 2 backslashes instead of 1, like `\\?`, did not work either.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you tried `?` without escaping it?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. ? has a special significance in Regex, it makes the preceding character optional

Comment: No. it doesn't work, pretty pointless to give something a try when there is a clear spec that states it's use and behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try surrounding in parens:

```
$route['(.+)/schoolid(?)'] = 'somepage';
```

Testing here locally, this seems to work.

Here is my `routes.php`:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(.+)/schoolid(?)'] = 'test2/index';//echo's "test"
```

`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ci-214/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|bootstrap)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

These URL's all work (do not produce 404 and echo test from `test2/index`):

```
http://example/ci-214/safgfgf/schoolid?/123
http://example/ci-214/safgfgf/schoolid?123
http://example/ci-214/sadf/schoolid?123
http://example/ci-214/sadf/schoolid?/
http://example/ci-214/sadf/schoolid?
http://example/ci-214/sadf/schoolid
```

Comment: Strange. Works for me here locally. Is there other stuff going on you haven't mentioned? Other routes? Trying to do something with what comes after the `?`?

Comment: I mean, I tried to do this 'random/schoolid? and that did not work.

Comment: thanks for the elaborate example,will need to go check out if my .htaccess was running into conflicts

Comment: that was it, I had a server side cache problem, phew!